# Gson handle object or array

Tags: gson

I've got the following classes

```
public class MyClass {
    private List<MyOtherClass> others;
}

public class MyOtherClass {
    private String name;
}
```

And I have JSON that may look like this

```
{
  others: {
    name: "val"
  }
}
```

or this

```
{
  others: [
    {
      name: "val"
    },
    {
      name: "val"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to be able to use the same `MyClass` for both of these JSON formats. Is there a way to do this with Gson?

Comment: The question is, who generates Json like this? Is it valid Json? If it is, Gson should handle it. If not, the "real" solution should be to fix the producer.

Comment: I totally agree that this is not a great way to write JSON. Unfortunately, we don't always have control over the data that we consume, so fixing the producer is not always an option. It is valid JSON, since JSON is schema-less.

Comment: Agreed with @three-cups

Answer (score 80):

I came up with an answer.

```java
private static class MyOtherClassTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<List<MyOtherClass>> {
    public List<MyOtherClass> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext ctx) {
        List<MyOtherClass> vals = new ArrayList<MyOtherClass>();
        if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            for (JsonElement e : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
                vals.add((MyOtherClass) ctx.deserialize(e, MyOtherClass.class));
            }
        } else if (json.isJsonObject()) {
            vals.add((MyOtherClass) ctx.deserialize(json, MyOtherClass.class));
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected JSON type: " + json.getClass());
        }
        return vals;
    }
}
```

Instantiate a Gson object like this

```java
Type myOtherClassListType = new TypeToken<List<MyOtherClass>>() {}.getType();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(myOtherClassListType, new MyOtherClassTypeAdapter())
        .create();
```

That `TypeToken` is a `com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken`.

You can read about the solution here:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I had a case where the JSON would return a single object or set of them.

Comment: Thanks. This is great. I needed two different TypeAdapters so I chained them by adding another .registerTypeAdapter

Comment: Why Gson is not putting just annotation to accept array or object of same format? This is highly demanded.

Comment: Cool ! and just remind for others, don't forget to `implements JsonDeserializer<List<MyOtherClass>>`, otherwise it doesn't work

Answer (score 9):

Thank you **three-cups** for the solution!

The same thing with generic type in case it's needed for multiple types:

```
public class SingleElementToListDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<List<T>> {

private final Class<T> clazz;

public SingleElementToListDeserializer(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

public List<T> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    List<T> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (json.isJsonArray()) {
        for (JsonElement e : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
            resultList.add(context.<T>deserialize(e, clazz));
        }
    } else if (json.isJsonObject()) {
        resultList.add(context.<T>deserialize(json, clazz));
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected JSON type: " + json.getClass());
    }
    return resultList;
    }
}
```

And configuring Gson:

```
Type myOtherClassListType = new TypeToken<List<MyOtherClass>>() {}.getType();
SingleElementToListDeserializer<MyOtherClass> adapter = new SingleElementToListDeserializer<>(MyOtherClass.class);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(myOtherClassListType, adapter)
    .create();
```

Answer (score 2):

to share code, and to only apply the deserialization logic to specific fields:

JSON model:

```java
public class AdminLoginResponse implements LoginResponse
{
    public Login login;
    public Customer customer;
    @JsonAdapter(MultiOrganizationArrayOrObject.class)    // <-------- look here
    public RealmList<MultiOrganization> allAccounts;
}
```

field-specific class:

```kotlin
class MultiOrganizationArrayOrObject
    : ArrayOrSingleObjectTypeAdapter<RealmList<MultiOrganization>,MultiOrganization>(kClass()) {
    override fun List<MultiOrganization>.toTypedList() = RealmList(*this.toTypedArray())
}
```

abstract class:

```kotlin
/**
 * parsed field can either be a [JSONArray] of type [Element], or an single [Element] [JSONObject].
 */
abstract class ArrayOrSingleObjectTypeAdapter<TypedList: List<Element>, Element : Any>(
    private val elementKClass: KClass<Element>
) : JsonDeserializer<TypedList> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type?, ctx: JsonDeserializationContext
    ): TypedList = when {
        json.isJsonArray -> json.asJsonArray.map { ctx.deserialize<Element>(it, elementKClass.java) }
        json.isJsonObject -> listOf(ctx.deserialize<Element>(json, elementKClass.java))
        else -> throw RuntimeException("Unexpected JSON type: " + json.javaClass)
    }.toTypedList()
    abstract fun List<Element>.toTypedList(): TypedList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off three-cups answer, I have the following which lets the JsonArray be deserialized directly as an array.

```
static public <T> T[] fromJsonAsArray(Gson gson, JsonElement json, Class<T> tClass, Class<T[]> tArrClass)
        throws JsonParseException {

    T[] arr;

    if(json.isJsonObject()){
        //noinspection unchecked
        arr = (T[]) Array.newInstance(tClass, 1);
        arr[0] = gson.fromJson(json, tClass);
    }else if(json.isJsonArray()){
        arr = gson.fromJson(json, tArrClass);
    }else{
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected JSON type: " + json.getClass());
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Usage:

```
    String response = ".......";

    JsonParser p = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement json = p.parse(response);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MyQuote[] quotes = GsonUtils.fromJsonAsArray(gson, json, MyQuote.class, MyQuote[].class);
```