# Extracting an array from a JSON object

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I have a JSON Object of the following and I need to parse the **path** strings inside the **web** array into an new JSON array.

```
"taxonomy": {
    "source": {
        "master": {
            "_id": "5000",
            "path": "/Appliances/Refrigerators/French Door Bottom Freezers"
        },
        "web": [
            {
                "_id": "6686",
                "path": "/Appliances/Refrigerators/French Door Bottom Freezers"
            },
            {
                "_id": "7686",
                "path": "/Appliances/Refrigerators/Bottom Freezers"
            }
        ],

    },

},
```

I have written till this but I'm not sure how to get all the **path** inside the **web** array.

```
                JSONObject jsonTaxonomy= _blob.optJSONObject("taxonomy");
            if(jsonTaxonomy!=null)
            {
                if(!jsonTaxonomy.isNull("source"))
                {
                    JSONObject jsonTaxonomySource= jsonTaxonomy.optJSONObject("source");
                    if(!jsonTaxonomySource.isNull("web"))
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonTaxonomySourceWeb= jsonTaxonomySource.optJSONArray("web");
                        if(jsonTaxonomySourceWeb!=null && jsonTaxonomySourceWeb.length()>0)
                        {
                            //Got inside the array
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `if(jsonTaxonomy!=null){ if(!jsonTaxonomy.isNull("source")){ }}` can be replaced with `if(jsonTaxonomy!=null && !jsonTaxonomy.isNull("source")){ }`

Comment: u need all source value to be added in web array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without providing you with a full answer, I'm convinced you'll be able to find your answer by debugging this method and stopping it at the most inner `if()`. You'll be able to of what `jsonTaxonomySearsWeb` consists and thus how to get its values.

Comment: Will using jsonTaxonomySearsWeb.getJSONObject(i).getString("path") and adding them to an array will work???

Comment: I'm no expert on `JSONObject`, but if this is part of a loop and `i` is provided by it, this probably will work.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to something like this:-

```
JSONObject jsonTaxonomy= _blob.optJSONObject("taxonomy");
if(jsonTaxonomy!=null)
{
        JSONObject jsonTaxonomySource = jsonTaxonomy.optJSONObject("source");
        if(jsonTaxonomySource!=null)
        {
            JSONArray jsonTaxonomySearsWeb= jsonTaxonomySource.optJSONArray("web");
            if(jsonTaxonomySearsWeb!=null)
            {
                // Traverse through your JSONArray and get each Object & extract path from it.
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am bit unclear about the question. But As per my understanding you want to parse the JSON if you want to do that in java then you can use GSON jar from google...you can also check simple example here [Gson handle object or array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668507/gson-handle-object-or-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

> ```
>       groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
>       System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
>       for (int i = 0; i < groups.length(); i++) {
>       JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
>       String source = c.getString(TAG_SOURCE);
>       System.out.println("Checking ::"+source);
>       String lname = c.getString(TAG_PATH);
>       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
>       map.put(TAG_SOURCE, source);
>       map.put(TAG_PATH,path);
>       weblist.add(map);       //weblist is your arraylist for both values
>       webpathlist.add(path);   //webpathlist is your arraylist for path
>        }
>       List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
>       newList.addAll(weblist);
> ```