# Transform JSON into java object call to a url

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a java project with Spring and quierao make a call to a `URL`, which returns me an array in `JSON` and have to be converted into a `ArrayList` of objects in Java .

In making the call with php and curl java json_decode but not how.

Example url :

```
http://localhost:8080/bets/province/by-country/196?_=1389005519239
```

And returns:

```
[
    {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "A Coruña"
    },
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Álava"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Albacete"
    },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Alicante"
    },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Almería"
    },
    {
    "id": 33,
    "name": "Asturias"
    },
    {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Ávila"
    },
    {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Badajoz"
    },
    {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Baleares (Illes)"
    },
    {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Barcelona"
    },
    {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Burgos"
    },
    {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Cáceres"
    },
    {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Cádiz"
    },
    {
    "id": 39,
    "name": "Cantabria"
    },
    {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Castellón"
    },
    {
    "id": 51,
    "name": "Ceuta"
    },
    {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Ciudad Real"
    },
    {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Córdoba"
    },
    {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "Cuenca"
    },
    {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "Girona"
    },
    {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "Granada"
    },
    {
    "id": 19,
    "name": "Guadalajara"
    },
    {
    "id": 20,
    "name": "Guipúzcoa"
    },
    {
    "id": 21,
    "name": "Huelva"
    },
    {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Huesca"
    },
    {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Jaén"
    },
    {
    "id": 26,
    "name": "La Rioja"
    },
    {
    "id": 35,
    "name": "Las Palmas"
    },
    {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "León"
    },
    {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Lleida"
    },
    {
    "id": 27,
    "name": "Lugo"
    },
    {
    "id": 28,
    "name": "Madrid"
    },
    {
    "id": 29,
    "name": "Málaga"
    },
    {
    "id": 52,
    "name": "Melilla"
    },
    {
    "id": 30,
    "name": "Murcia"
    },
    {
    "id": 31,
    "name": "Navarra"
    },
    {
    "id": 32,
    "name": "Ourense"
    },
    {
    "id": 34,
    "name": "Palencia"
    },
    {
    "id": 36,
    "name": "Pontevedra"
    },
    {
    "id": 37,
    "name": "Salamanca"
    },
    {
    "id": 38,
    "name": "Santa Cruz de Tenerife"
    },
    {
    "id": 40,
    "name": "Segovia"
    },
    {
    "id": 41,
    "name": "Sevilla"
    },
    {
    "id": 42,
    "name": "Soria"
    },
    {
    "id": 43,
    "name": "Tarragona"
    },
    {
    "id": 44,
    "name": "Teruel"
    },
    {
    "id": 45,
    "name": "Toledo"
    },
    {
    "id": 46,
    "name": "Valencia"
    },
    {
    "id": 47,
    "name": "Valladolid"
    },
    {
    "id": 48,
    "name": "Vizcaya"
    },
    {
    "id": 49,
    "name": "Zamora"
    },
    {
    "id": 50,
    "name": "Zaragoza"
    }
]
```

And I wanted to save a List  , someone can put me an example?
Thanks and regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gson handle object or array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668507/gson-handle-object-or-array)

Comment: In this post is not answered and make the call to the url and get the json object and that is also the question that I have, thanks.

Comment: What is your preferred output ?

Comment: My idea is to call the url with something like curl php and then serialize the json object received in a java arraylist to use in my controller. Thank you.