# Retrofit 2.x custom type adapter

Tags: javascript, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2.x.I have to parse a json response whose structure is as follows:

- ->query(object)

  - -->results(object)

    - --->Scorecard(can be list or object)

      - ---->past_ings(can be list or object)
      - ---->result(can be primitive or object)

here is the link for the json test response that contains all the scenarios listed above-[json](http://spmysql.site88.net/test.json)

Please suggest a way to do so:)

Comment: I suggest looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668507/gson-handle-object-or-array. It answers many of your questions.