# Handling more than 1 response in retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

i Have 2 responses in my api response one for success if the data is correct and one for incorrect data i can't handle it with my pojo class and this is my class

```
public class AirCraftSearchResponse {

@SerializedName("Data")
@Expose
private Data data;
@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private Object message;
public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Object getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(Object message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

and this is the two responses of faill

```
{
"Success": false,
"Message": "Could not convert string to DateTime: 2019-12-08T0000:00. Path 'Legs[0].DateTime', line 1, position 1185.",
"Data": [],
"total": 0
}
```

and success response is

```
{
"Success": true,
"Message": "",
"Data": {},
"total": 0
}
```

when i make response and i get success there is no problem happen because my pojo class have same object for response and when i get fail it make exception and i can't handle or get it's message because it goes to onFailure method 
when i print it's message i get this line

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 143 path $.Data
```

Comment: i cant understand you can you explain it to me ?

Comment: you can write your own custom convertor by looking into the examples on retrofit github repo

Comment: thank you for you comment but i can't get the solution :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668507/gson-handle-object-or-array this should help

Comment: @codekidX i try your link put i get another exception i can't cast object to model i try this line
            MyPOJO myObj = (MyPOJO) response.body(); and i convert data to Object and it give me another exception

Comment: @Raghunandan i will try this thank thank you ^_^ but i want simple way to handle it like make it as Object and convert it to pojo model

Answer (score 0):

The problem itself says

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

The issue with your value type of key **"data"**. In success, you are sending Object i.e. {} and in case of failure, you are sending an array i.e. []. Try to send object {} in failure and your problem would be solved.

Right fomat below for failure

```
{
 "Success": false,
 "Message": "Could not convert string to DateTime: 2019-12-08T0000:00. 
 Path 'Legs[0].DateTime', line 1, position 1185.",
 "Data": {},
 "total": 0
}
```

Comment: It's a format problem from backend or wherever you are creating that JSON.

Comment: it's not request iam don't sending this data its back to me from api response and its back with two ways i want to handle it and i can't edit in api structure it's not my api

Comment: i know it's wrong format from back end and i want to handle it by creating 2 model or something like that you understand me ?

Comment: In that case, you need to serialize the data after receiving the JSON. Or Write your own Gson deserializer for your Data element. This would check whether the data element is an object or an array.

Comment: i don't know how to serialize the data can you explain to me ? how to maka it or how to make gson deserializer