# GSON : Parsing JSON key value with sometime Object & sometime Array

Tags: android, gson

I am using GSON for parsing JSON String but there is key contains Json which is sometime object and sometimes array.
 So please help me for parse it to model class using gson.

> Resonse with Array

```
{
   "key" : "test",
   "value" : [
                {
                  "id" : 1,
                  "name": "abc"
                },
                {
                  "id" : 2,
                  "name": "xyz"
                }
             ]
}
```

> Resonse with Object

```
{
   "key" : "test",
   "value" : {
                 "id" : 1,
                 "name": "abc"
             }
}
```

> MyModel.java

```
public class MyModel implements Serializable {
@SerializedName("key")
@Expose
public String key;

@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
public ArrayList<ValueModel> value;

public class ValueModel implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    public String id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;
   }
}
```

But it always goto in exeption because of datatype array and object
I also tried with JsonDeserializer but i think i didnt implement it well
So please help me to resolve it and parse json

Comment: Simple way just change the response from back end side ask your back end developer to give response in same format every time

Comment: I am using third party API and it has this type of response. How can i told him to change response for me ?

Comment: Do you know in which circumstances `object` will appear instead of an `array` and vice versa?

Comment: When there is only one value then it becomes object else Array

Comment: I also require answer for same question.

Answer (score 1):

Simple try to access as Object then check the instanceof  Object and parse data based on that

```
String json="";

JSONObject jsonMain=new JSONObject(json);

Object objectType=jsonMain.get("value");
  if (objectType instanceof JSONObject) {
    JSONObject jsonObjectType=(JSONObject)objectType;
  } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
    JSONArray jsonArrayType=(JSONArray)objectType;
  }
```

If you are using JSONObject

```
  if (objectType  instanceof JSONObject) {
     UserDetails details = new Gson().fromJson(objectType, UserDetails.class);

 } else if (objectType  instanceof JSONArray) {
     Type listType = new TypeToken<List<UserDetails>>() {
     }.getType();
     List<UserDetails> list = new Gson().fromJson(objectType, listType);
     userDetailsList.addAll(list);
 }
```

Comment: I got your answer but according to it i determine it only it is object or array but i want to convert object to array if. And this functionality provides by GSON. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668507/gson-handle-object-or-array

Comment: I want to handle it into model itself

Comment: @SandipPatel i have updated the answer,you need t use mixture of both model handling and manual parsing,because JSONResponse  is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

Add SerializedName name for object also and add custom getter

```
public class MyModel implements Serializable {
      @SerializedName("key")
      @Expose
      public String key;

      @SerializedName("value")
      @Expose
      public ArrayList<ValueModel> valueList;

      @SerializedName("value")
      @Expose
      ValueModel modelValue;

      public List<ValueModel> getValueModel() {
          return Collections.singletonList(modelValue);
       }

public class ValueModel implements Serializable {
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        public String id;

        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        public String name;
       }
     }
```

Comment: I want to convert object to array if there is object and if array then its ok.

Comment: It can be done by using JsonDeserializer or JsonAdapter but i dont know how to implement it. If you know then please help me to implement it. Thanks.

Comment: i update my answer please check that, You can also use

`public List<ValueModel> getValueModel () {
        return Arrays.asList(modelValue);
    }`

Comment: You have used two different object for single key "value". But GSON provides JsonAdapter or JsonDeserializer for that but i cant understand it well. please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668507/gson-handle-object-or-array

Comment: Thank you for give me a new valuable information. you can use JsonAdapter ( like the link you posted ) to solve your problem.

Comment: But i didn't get it well they used it at the time of parsing but i want to use it inside model.

Comment: did you try my method??

Comment: In GSON there is annotation available @JsonAdapter. It must be used JsonAdapter class for deserialization. But how ? i don't know?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
gson.fromJson(jsonString, classOfModel)
```

And I think you can remove `@SerializedName` and `@Expose` tags.

Answer (score 0):

**In Case you didn't find the answer. 
Check this.**

```
public class SomeModel  {

    @SerializedName("my_model")
     private MyModel[] myModel;

    public List<MyModel> getMyModel() {

       return new LinkedList<MyModel>( Arrays.asList(myModel));

    }

     public static class MyModelDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyModel[]> {

    @Override
     public MyModel[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
     JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

      if (json instanceof JsonArray) {

            return new Gson().fromJson(json, MyModel[].class);

      }

      MyModel child = context.deserialize(json, MyModel.class);

         return new MyModel[] { child };
      }
  }
}
```

reference: https://nayaneshguptetechstuff.wordpress.com/2014/06/21/parsing-json-with-gson-sometimes-object-sometimes-array/